# Hibernate persist object graph spread in two database

Tags: hibernate

If one object I need to save in database with some property that needs to be save in some different database what should be my approach?

### Example

```
Calss Address
{
    String owner_name,
    String house_no,
}

Class Employee
{
    List<Address> addLst;
}
```

In some situation I have `Address` table in `DB1` and `Employee` table in `DB2` and I need to save employee *object* at one go.

I know that hibernate is not suitable in this situation but is there any way so that I can get the results below?

**DB1:**

```
EMPLOYEE
----------
emp_id  Addredd_id
1       1
```

**DB2:**

```
ADDRESS
----------
address_id   Owner   House_no
1            abc     BD/12
```

There are no constraints from database side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postFlush listener - when the Employee object is flushed to the database you can get hold of the address list and save it using a different session.

You will need to do the same for loading as well.

This approach will lead you to a lot of problems later on.

It is better to have a wrapper function that saves these two things separately and use that from every where else.